# Want to run query from specific time of today to last n hours

Tags: oracle

Hi I want to run a query which extracts data from 7:00 am in the morning to 3:00 pm yesterday.

I run this query in afternoon.

Below query extracts data from time I run the query. I want the data from 7:00 am and backwards.

```
select *
from NOTES
where creation_date >= sysdate- interval '17:15' hour to minute
```

I would appreciate any help.

Comment: Can't you just use BETWEEN command `SELECT * FROM actor WHERE last_update BETWEEN '2016-02-02 15:00:00' AND '2016-02-03 07:00:00';`

Comment: Query has to be run daily. I need to hand it over to someone for running daily. So i thought of  keeping it as simple as possible for him.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in Oracle:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM NOTES 
 WHERE creation_date BETWEEN to_timestamp(to_char(sysdate) || ' 00:00:00', 'dd-Mon-yy hh24:mi:ss') - interval '9' hour
   AND to_timestamp(to_char(sysdate) || ' 00:00:00', 'dd-Mon-yy hh24:mi:ss') + interval '7' hour;
```

Try this in MySQL:

```
SELECT *
  FROM NOTES
 WHERE creation_date >= (concat(current_date(), ' 00:00:00') - interval '09:00' hour) 
   AND creation_date <= (concat(current_date(), ' 00:00:00') + interval '07:00' hour);
```

Comment: Sorry, this doesn't work. 
 ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis
I might have forgot to mention I am running this in oracle.
But I changed the currentdate to sysdate for those purposes.

Comment: Update your tags accordingly. It currently says _mysql_.

Comment: Edited the answer for Oracle as well.

Comment: I am sorry, I had tagged it as sysdate, not sure how it changed to mysql.
I am new to this forum(in terms of posting questions)

Answer (score 0):

Try this as optimal

For Oracle

```
SELECT * 
   FROM NOTES 
  WHERE creation_date BETWEEN trunc(sysdate) - INTERVAL '9' HOUR 
                          AND trunc(curdate) + INTERVAL '7' HOUR;
```

For MySQL

```
 SELECT * 
   FROM NOTES 
  WHERE creation_date BETWEEN curdate() - INTERVAL 9 HOUR 
                          AND curdate() + INTERVAL 7 HOUR;
```

If you need detail info - just ask.

Comment: I am using oracle database so curdate won't work.
Anyways curdate calculates 9 hours from current time not 12:00 am

Comment: Ok, I see the you are specify db after my answer :) No problem. For Oracle it is almost the same - only functions are diffrent, but idea is the same. 
I edit my answer.

About "Anyways curdate calculates 9 hours from current time not 12:00 am" - you say that you want from 3pm yestarday to 7am today. If we extract 9 hours from midnight, the result is 3pm 0 as you want.